# No longer an option to upload to iCloud with iTunes Match and iTunes 12.2.2?

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match, apple-music

I've been trying out the new Apple Music service and saw some odd behaviors, so decided I should update my iTunes to 12.2.2 (I think I was on 12.0 or 12.1 previously).  Since the update, there is no longer any way that I can see, to add a track (one that I added to the library manually, for example) to the iCloud library.

Where did this feature go?  We used to be able to just right click the track and Add to iCloud Music Library, but no longer.  Also almost all of my tracks no longer have any indication of an iCloud Status, and of those that do - many are inexplicably not present in my local library and indicate that they need to be downloaded.

What gives here?  I haven't been able to find anything on these specific issues in my searches.  Is there some known problem here or am I just not understanding how iCloud music works now?  In fact I can't even find any evidence of iTunes Match existing any longer in iTunes.  No menu items, no preferences, etc.

To be clear, this has nothing at all to do with iOS and is concerned strictly with iTunes on OS X (Mavericks in my case).

**EDIT:  To add to this, I just noticed that only a few of my tracks still have the "Add to iCloud Music Library" option - specifically those tracks which are marked as duplicates.  Not a single other track in my entire library of 15,421 tracks, has that option anymore despite being an iTunes Match subscriber.  Can anyone shed some light on this?**

**EDIT 2:**

OK, after a bit more investigation I think it may just be that the way iTunes handles iCloud music has changed with the introduction of Apple Music.  According to [this apple KB article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204925), it sounds like your entire library is now *automatically* uploaded and matched.  But what still confuses me is that there is absolutely no possible way Apple could have matched all of my music - because some of it is original work created by myself that exists nowhere else.  And those tracks - and many others - are also still missing the Add to iCloud Music Library option.  Are they added anyway but there is simply no longer any indication in iTunes of this fact?  If I attempt to delete one of these tracks, I'm given the option to Remove Download, so presumably they are indeed already in the cloud (and were before I upgraded iTunes, so that is in fact what I expect).  Maybe the real question here is:  **Why does iTunes no longer display an indicator for tracks that have been uploaded to the cloud?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just experienced the same thing and found that it looks like iTunes Match might have just been renamed and the settings moved.

Note for future readers, I am using iTunes version 12.2.2.25 (64 bit) on Windows 10.

Make sure you are logged in to the iTunes Store and also make sure your computer is authorized (see the Store menu item), and then try going to **File** > **Library** > **Update iCloud Music Library**. After selecting that menu item, look in the top right corner (where you would normally see anything downloading) and you should see this:
[image: iTunes updating iCloud Music Library]

After waiting for this to finish, my entire iTunes Match library appeared back! (This took about 10 minutes or so).

Also, to answer your question about the display indicator, as far as I can tell this behaves exactly as iTunes Match did for me previously. I can see which songs are downloaded, and I can choose to download those that haven't by clicking the cloud symbol.

Answer (score -2):

Open iTunes, go to iTunes > Preference > General, and check iCloud Music Library > click OK.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Good answers are well thought out, provide context, and are well-written. Try reading the [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com//help/how-to-answer) page. Can you give more of an explanation? For example, could you tell us what this does and why it works?

Comment: This answer is not helpful.  The issue is not that I am not using the iCloud Music Library.  It is already enabled, and your answer does not address the question.